# Content shrinks on screens of small width

Tags: html, css, viewport

I was testing my website in Chrome inspector (mobile device mode) and noticed that when screen width becomes less than about 350px, the footer starts to shrink as shown on picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9cA1.png

(but all other elements don't). And also I've noticed that if screen is less than 350px in width, the output of `visualViewport.scale` in console returns the value less than `1`.

My meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

I didn't put the page code here, because it will be too much. What could possibly cause a problem?

UPD: Added snippet.

```css
footer {
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: auto;
    background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
    color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
}

.footer-cont {
    padding: 0 5%;
}

.footer-line {
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.footer-line-cont {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    font-weight: 500;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.footer-line-text {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.social {
    height: 100%;
}

.social-icon {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px 15px;
}

.footer-flex {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-flex-text {
    line-height: 1.8em;
    max-width: 400px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.footer-flex-contacts {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    max-width: 400px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.footer-flex-contacts span {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    white-space: pre;
    margin: 0px 0;
}

.orderButtonFoot {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 18px 16px;
    margin: 12px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 200ms ease, padding 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease, padding 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease, padding 0s;
}

.orderButtonFoot:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: white;
}

.footer-remarks {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.footer-remarks p {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}

.copyright-cont {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.bugreport {
    text-align: right;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .bugreport {
        display: none;
    }

    .copyright-cont {
        justify-content: center;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .footer-line {
        height: 80px;
        padding: 10px 5%;
    }

    .footer-flex {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .footer-flex-text {
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .footer-flex-contacts {
        margin: auto;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .orderButtonFoot {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}



header {
    background-color: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.95);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menuButton {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    width: 65px;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}

.logo {
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Fredoka One', Arial;
    line-height: 65px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}

.margin-nav {
    height: 85px;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 5%;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

nav div ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    margin: 0px 3px;
}

nav div ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 16px;
}

nav div ul li a.active {
    color: rgb(155, 155, 155);
}

.orderButton {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 200ms ease, padding 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease, padding 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease, padding 0s;
}

.orderButton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    nav div ul {
        text-align: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 50px;
        transition: opacity 200ms ease;
    }
    
    nav div ul li {
        margin: 20px 3px;
    }
    
    nav {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .nav {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 0;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 400px;
        transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
    }

    .orderButton {
        padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .logo {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .menuButton {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav.active {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}

.flex-mob {
            display: flex;
            height: 60vh;
            text-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            margin: 30px 0;
            flex: 1;
            }
```

```html
<head>
<html>
 <body>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<header>
        <div class="menuButton">&#9776;</div>
    <nav>
        <a href="/" class="logo">Cite</a>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><div class="orderButton">Заказать</div></li>
                <li><a href="/about.php" id="aboutBtn">О нас</a></li>
                <li><a href="#bottom" id="contactsBtn">Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </header>
  <div class="flex-mob">
        <div class="flex-text-mob">
            <h2>Адаптивный дизайн</h2>
            <p>Одинаково хорошо отображается как на мобильных устройствах, так и на десктопах и ноутбуках.</p>
        </div>  
        <div class="flex-device"></div>
        <div class="flex-text-mob">
            <h2>Портрет | ландшафт</h2>
            <p>Элементы дизайна подстраиваются под ориентацию экрана и размеры окна.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
            <div class="footer-line footer-cont">
                <div class="footer-line-cont">
                    <div class="footer-line-text">Связь с нами:</div>
                    <div class="social">
                        <img class="social-icon" src="images/inst.png" alt="instagram">
                        <img class="social-icon" src="images/telegram.png" alt="telegram">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-cont">
                <div class="footer-flex">
                    <div class="footer-flex-text">
                        Остались вопросы? Вы всегда можете связаться с нами и уточнить интересующие детали.
                    </div>
                    <div class="s25"></div>
                    <div class="footer-flex-contacts">
                        <span>+38 (095) 415 31 56</span>
                        <span><a href="mailto:support@cite.dev">support@cite.eu.org</a></span>
                        <button type="button" class="orderButtonFoot">Заказать</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-remarks">
                    <p><sup>1</sup> Домен оплачивается заказчиком отдельно раз в год, согласно тарифа регистратора.</p>
                    <p><sup>2</sup> Хостинг также оплачивается заказчиком отдельно. Мы не несем ответственности за изменение тарифов хостинг-провайдеров и регистраторов.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="copyright-cont">
                <div class="copyright">
                    <?php echo '&copy; Cite, ' . date("Y") . '. Сайты на заказ.' ?>
                </div>
                <div class="bugreport">
                    Нашли ошибку или баг на сайте? Сообшите нам.
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/zenscroll.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not too much code, it's just the code relevant to your question.  You don't need post all of them here. See, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added some elements to snippet, but I cannot reproduce the above-mentioned behaviour here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. I am not sure if it is the best way to workaround this problem but it is still here.

**SOLUTION:** I `added min-width: 360px` to the whole body and then removed `initial-scale` from meta tag (to prevent appearing a horizontal scroll if screen width less than 360px).

But now all elements with `heigh: 100%` or `100vh` are less than actual screen height on screens less than 360px and `visualViewport.scale` is still less than `1`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that content in the `.flex-mob` element prevents it from shrinking beyond a certain width, while the footer continues to shrink. You might also get a horizontal scroll bar.

I typically use a "mobile first" design, in which baseline CSS defines the smallest screen size (phone) and the media queries are applied at larger sizes, using `@media (min-width...`. I have not changed all of your CSS to follow this strategy, but I added a definition for `.flex-mob` that applies flexbox only on screens that are at least 600px wide.

I also removed the margin from `<body>`, as [suggested by カメロン](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71316892/924299).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
}

.footer-cont {
  padding: 0 5%;
}

.footer-line {
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.footer-line-cont {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  font-weight: 500;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer-line-text {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.social {
  height: 100%;
}

.social-icon {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

.footer-flex {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-flex-text {
  line-height: 1.8em;
  max-width: 400px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.footer-flex-contacts {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  max-width: 400px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.footer-flex-contacts span {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  white-space: pre;
  margin: 0px 0;
}

.orderButtonFoot {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 16px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms ease, padding 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease, padding 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease, padding 0s;
}

.orderButtonFoot:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
}

.footer-remarks {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.footer-remarks p {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.copyright-cont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.bugreport {
  text-align: right;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .bugreport {
    display: none;
  }
  .copyright-cont {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .footer-line {
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px 5%;
  }
  .footer-flex {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .footer-flex-text {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .footer-flex-contacts {
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .orderButtonFoot {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

header {
  background-color: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.95);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menuButton {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  width: 65px;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', Arial;
  line-height: 65px;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.margin-nav {
  height: 85px;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 5%;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

nav div ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0px 3px;
}

nav div ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 16px;
}

nav div ul li a.active {
  color: rgb(155, 155, 155);
}

.orderButton {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms ease, padding 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease, padding 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease, padding 0s;
}

.orderButton:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  nav div ul {
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 50px;
    transition: opacity 200ms ease;
  }
  nav div ul li {
    margin: 20px 3px;
  }
  nav {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
  }
  .orderButton {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .logo {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menuButton {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav.active {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .flex-mob {
    display: flex;
    height: 60vh;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 30px 0;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="menuButton">&#9776;</div>
  <nav>
    <a href="/" class="logo">Cite</a>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="orderButton">Заказать</div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/about.php" id="aboutBtn">О нас</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bottom" id="contactsBtn">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="flex-mob">
  <div class="flex-text-mob">
    <h2>Адаптивный дизайн</h2>
    <p>Одинаково хорошо отображается как на мобильных устройствах, так и на десктопах и ноутбуках.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-device"></div>
  <div class="flex-text-mob">
    <h2>Портрет | ландшафт</h2>
    <p>Элементы дизайна подстраиваются под ориентацию экрана и размеры окна.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="footer-line footer-cont">
    <div class="footer-line-cont">
      <div class="footer-line-text">Связь с нами:</div>
      <div class="social">
        <img class="social-icon" src="images/inst.png" alt="instagram">
        <img class="social-icon" src="images/telegram.png" alt="telegram">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-cont">
    <div class="footer-flex">
      <div class="footer-flex-text">
        Остались вопросы? Вы всегда можете связаться с нами и уточнить интересующие детали.
      </div>
      <div class="s25"></div>
      <div class="footer-flex-contacts">
        <span>+38 (095) 415 31 56</span>
        <span><a href="mailto:support@cite.dev">support@cite.eu.org</a></span>
        <button type="button" class="orderButtonFoot">Заказать</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-remarks">
      <p><sup>1</sup> Домен оплачивается заказчиком отдельно раз в год, согласно тарифа регистратора.</p>
      <p><sup>2</sup> Хостинг также оплачивается заказчиком отдельно. Мы не несем ответственности за изменение тарифов хостинг-провайдеров и регистраторов.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="copyright-cont">
    <div class="copyright">
      <?php echo '&copy; Cite, ' . date("Y") . '. Сайты на заказ.' ?>
    </div>
    <div class="bugreport">
      Нашли ошибку или баг на сайте? Сообшите нам.
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already have all margins and paddings equal to 0 by default (on * selector). And I want to say that after some experiments I found out that if I set the min-width: 360px to footer or the whole body, it stops shrinking. But in this case I have horizontal scroll bar on page load and need to manually zoom-out.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, `min-w-fit` in tailwind, or equivalenty, `min-width: fit-content` fixed it for me.